# List<class> does not contain definition for string

Tags: c#, json

I have declared a helper class to create a JSON. But I just doesn not want to work properly with Lists. Any suggestions to this code? The error occours when trying to set roleDescription and roleType value.

Error: 'List< generateCredentialsRoleList>' does not contain a definition for 'roleDescription '

Error: 'List< generateCredentialsRoleList>' does not contain a definition for 'roleType'

```
public class generateTokenRequest
{
    public generateToken generateToken { get; set; }
}
public class generateToken
{
    public List<generateCredentialsRoleList> credentialsRoleList { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class generateCredentialsRoleList
{
    public string roleDescription { get; set; }
    public string roleType { get; set; }
}

public string generateTokenRequest(string roleDescription, string roleType, string description)

{
    generateTokenRequest generateTokenRequest = new generateTokenRequest
    {
        generateToken = new generateToken
        {
            credentialsRoleList = new List<generateCredentialsRoleList>
            {
                roleDescription = roleDescription,
                roleType = roleType,

            },
            description = description,
        }

    };
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(generateTokenRequest, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

    return json;
}
```

Comment: What does "just doesn not want to work properly" mean?

Comment: I try to say that I anything I try the generateCredentialsRoleList has errors. If I dont use lists the above works fine. Just trying to create list fails for me and I cant compile this because of errors

Comment: Which error? Compiler error?

Comment: Error: 'List<generateCredentialsRoleList>' does not contain a definition for 'roleType'

Comment: It would be awesome if you used standard C# naming conventions, and not Java conventions.

Comment: @Enigmativity could you tell me where is the problem and the difference?

Comment: Ah I see I use everywhere camelCase but I should use also PascalCase like in class names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
credentialsRoleList = new List<generateCredentialsRoleList>
{
    roleDescription = roleDescription,
    roleType = roleType,

},
```

you try to initialize a list. A list takes items. You don't provide items, you provide *property values* of an item.

How to fix this depends on what you actually want to do. Do you want to initialize the list with a *single item* containing those properties? That would be done as follows:

```
credentialsRoleList = new List<generateCredentialsRoleList>
{
    new generateCredentialsRoleList()
    {
        roleDescription = roleDescription,
        roleType = roleType
    }
    // you could add more items to your list here, if you wanted
},
```

Some additional recommendations:

- `generateCredentialsRoleList` is not a good name of the *item* in a list. It's like calling a single apple a "bag of apples".
- When asking a question on StackOverflow, please always provide **the complete error message** you get right in the question. Sometimes the cause of an error is obvious, but most of the time it isn't, and the precise error message helps.

Comment: Just want to emphasize that altough the question is really basic, but this answer is really high quality one !

Comment: Thank you it works fine. The provided names are from API documentation where I try to send this JSON. Only added the 'generate' to class names.

Comment: @Tweene: Keep calling the property `credentialsRoleList`, that's fine. Just rename the class (which JSON doesn't care about anyways) to `generateCredentialsRole` instead of `generateCredentialsRoleList`. Believe me, that's a great help for anyone trying to read and understand the code in the future (which might as well be your future self).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add new item in list initializer like this:

```cs
generateToken = new generateToken
        {
            credentialsRoleList = new List<generateCredentialsRoleList>
            {
               new generateCredentialsRoleList() {
                  roleDescription = roleDescription,
                  roleType = roleType
                 }

            },
            description = description,
        }
```